# Convert String to Excel Time in VBA, with specific string format

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA, I have two string variables:

```vb
var1 = "2022-08-12T10:32:48.363402"
var2 = "2022-08-12T10:32:49.759310"
```

`var1` corresponds to the 12th Aug 2022, time 10:32:48.363402
`var2` corresponds to the 12th Aug 2022, time 10:32:49.759310

In VBA, I would like to convert these variables into date format in order to find the time difference between the two, in seconds.

For example, `var2-var1` = 10:32:49.759310 - 10:32:48.363402 should return 1.395908 seconds.

I tried using `TimeValue(10:32:49.759310)` but it does not work as it does not accept the mililseconds, it only works when the seconds value is in integer form, e.g. `TimeValue(10:32:49)`.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I Split the var1 to separate the date (2022-08-12) and time (10:32:48.363402) - both are still in string format using Split(). Then, I used TimeValue("10:32:48.363402") and it does not work, due to the seconds value not being an integer. Haven't found anything else online to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next function. It returns the **date Double value**, extracted from string, by adding each its component (Date itself + time + milliseconds time):

```
Function strToDateDbl(strD As String) As Double
    Dim arrStr, arrD, arrT, d As Date, dblTime As Double, dblTDecSec As Double
    arrStr = Split(strD, "T"): arrD = Split(arrStr(0), "-")
    d = DateSerial(CLng(arrD(0)), CLng(arrD(1)), CLng(arrD(2)))
    arrT = Split(arrStr(1), ":")
    dblTime = CDbl(CDate(Format(arrT(0) & ":" & arrT(1) & ":" & Int(arrT(2)), "hh:mm:ss"))) 'double of the time part
    dblTDecSec = CDbl((CDbl(arrT(2)) - Int(arrT(2))) / 86400)                                                       'double of milliseconds part
    strToDateDbl = CDbl(d) + dblTime + dblTDecSec
End Function
```

You can test it with the next sub:

```
Sub TestStrToDateDbl()
    Dim var1 As String, var2 As String, d1 As Double, d2 As Double
    var1 = "2022-08-12T10:32:48.363402": var2 = "2022-08-12T10:32:49.759310"
    d1 = strToDateDbl(var1)
    d2 = strToDateDbl(var2)
    Debug.Print Round((d2 - d1) * 86400, 6) '86400 number of seconds in a day...
End Sub
```

**Edited**:

Please, also test the next a little more compact version (inspired by Gustav code). I thought it is better to choose a solution without risk of erroring because of any localization and also to be more precise. I mean, Excel looks to `Round` the seconds decimals, not truncate them. Anyhow, the next function will return with reasonable accuracy:

```
Function strToDateDbl(strD As String) As Double
    Dim arrT, d As Date, dblTDecSec As Double
    d = CDate(Replace(left(strD, 19), "T", " ")): arrT = Split(strD, ":")
    
    dblTDecSec = CDbl((CDbl(arrT(UBound(arrT))) - Int(arrT(UBound(arrT)))) / 86400)    'double of milliseconds part
    strToDateDbl = CDbl(d) + dblTDecSec
End Function
```

Comment: @HereToLearnAndHelp I will try posting a more compact version (inspired by the above answer), but it may be returning with some rounding error (the last decimal, probable) because of Excel truncating the seconds...

Comment: It fails outside the US, because `Int` ignores the dot because that's our thousand separator, and `Format` returns a comma as the decimal separator. Thus, this only runs in a US environment.

Comment: @Gustav I tried an adapted function with reasonable accuracy (the six decimal...), because (I think) Excel rounds the seconds decimals, not truncate them... Your solution works well in terms of returning the date, but not fully accurate in terms of decimals... Anyhow, is obviously more compact...

Comment: @HereToLearnAndHelp Glad I could help! Please, try the second version (after **Edited**:) and see if it is accurate enough. Beside that, I will like to tell you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, tick the code left side, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the proposed solution works...

Comment: @FaneDuru Thanks for your help. I tested both versions and they both return the desired value. Ticked the code on the left. Helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method - also in an International environment:

```vb
    Dim Var1        As String
    Dim Var2        As String
    Dim Date1       As Date
    Dim Date2       As Date
    Dim MSeconds1   As Variant
    Dim MSeconds2   As Variant
    Dim Seconds     As Variant
    
    Var1 = "2022-08-12T10:32:48.363402"
    Var2 = "2022-08-12T10:32:49.759310"
    
    Date1 = CDate(Replace(Left(Var1, 19), "T", " "))
    Date2 = CDate(Replace(Left(Var2, 19), "T", " "))
    
    MSeconds1 = CDec(Val(Mid(Var1, 20)))
    MSeconds2 = CDec(Val(Mid(Var2, 20)))
    Seconds = DateDiff("s", Date1, Date2) + CDec(MSeconds2 - MSeconds1)
    
    Debug.Print Seconds
```

Returns the exact value:

```
1.395908
```

Comment: I am not sure that the difference will will be returned with decimals, as OP required... How would you declare the used variables to make them accepting seconds decimals?

Comment: This code returns 1s as the difference, not taking into account the milliseconds (i.e. decimals)

Comment: Yes, sorry. See modified answer, please.